# Meteor create user ranking by score

Tags: meteor, ranking

I'm a total beginner. I'm using Meteor for a school project and I'm trying to create a ranking. I want to rank users according to their score. I want to display their usernames with their scores.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7ksx.jpg)

the function I found to sort the users and the following one

`Meteor.users.find({}, { sort: { score: -1 } });`

I would like to include it in the following code

```
Template.classement.helpers({

  users() {
    Meteor.users.find().forEach(function(oneUser) {
      const affichage = `nom : ${oneUser.username} score : ${oneUser.profile.score}`;
      console.log(affichage);
      console.log(oneUser.profile.score);
      console.log(oneUser);
    });

    return Meteor.users.find();
  },


});
```

on the html side, I have this to display but it dosen't work

```
<template name="classement">
  <h1>Classement</h1>
 {{#each users}}
    {{user}}
  {{/each}} 
</template>
```

Could you please help me. (sorry for the grammar, English is not my first language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

The issue is in the sort:

```
Meteor.users.find({}, { sort: { score: -1 } });
```

This attempts to sort documents by the top level field `score`. While you have `score` stored in a sub-document, under profile.

The syntax to sort by an attribute of a submodule in MongoDB is this:

```
Meteor.users.find({}, { sort: { 'profile.score': -1 } });
```